# Conditionally rendering gifs on shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to render a gif on shiny based on a selection made by a user. For example if a user selects a given fighter, if I have saved a gif with the id associated with the selection, a gif would be rendered at the bottom of the web app.

This is the code I have:

```
   #select player name
   uiOutput("Names")
   #render gif
   imageOutput("gifs")
   #in server function
     output$Names <- renderUI({
       req(input$dropdown)
       df <- boxing %>% filter(division %in% input$dropdown)
       selectInput("names","Player A",choices = df$name)
     })
   #render gif from server
   output$gifs <- renderImage({
       tags$video(src=paste(boxing[boxing$name == input$names, "global_id"],".gif",sep="",type="video/gif"), width=100)
     })
```

Here is a sample of my data

```
   name      global_id
   Fox         121
   Jim         122
   Felix       123
   Joel        124
   Paul        125
```

These are the gifs in my www directors

```
123.gif
124.gif
```

If no gif exists I do not want to show anything for that particular player.

This is the error message I am currently getting

```
Error: invalid filename argument
```

Comment: I'm unable to test it, but I believe the error is in your `paste()`. Consider using a switch-case for referencing the gifs.

Comment: @mhh  it initially was, but now when I print out the paste() statement on my console I get the filename, but can't render the gif. I also get the filename as the output on the app

Comment: Do you get the same error after correcting the `paste()`?

Comment: @mhh no, I just get the filename

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the error is in your `paste()`. Try this:

```
output$gifs <- renderImage({
  tags$video(src=paste(boxing[boxing$name == input$names, "global_id"],".gif",sep=""),type="video/gif", width=100)
})
```

While your code works the way it is, you may also consider using a switch-case. However, this will be messy if you have a lot of characters/gifs. For example:

```
output$gifs <- renderImage({
  this_gif <- switch (input$names,
    "Fox" = 121,
    "Jim" = 122
    # Etc
  )
  tags$video(src=paste(this_gif,".gif", sep = ""),type="video/gif", width=100)
})
```

Comment: This solution is not extensible and in my book, could be improved. Perhaps using `grepl` or some other regex solution.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - could you elaborate on how it could be made more extensible? Another option would be to reference the filename in full in the `global_id`. Switch case also has the benefit of having a `default`action, as OP wanted to have an option to do nothing if nothing was selected.

Comment: I would construct a regex valid string to fetch the exact filename and use it in i.e. `grepl`. Another ption would be to have a lookup table of names, file names and ids and then match by id for unambiguity.